# avoid explicit passing of lookup table

Tags: haskell, recursion, arguments, monads, implicit

In my very simple boolean expression toy program, I have the following evaluation function:

```
eval' :: Expr -> M.Map Char Bool -> Bool

eval' (Const c) values = c

eval' (Var v)   values = M.findWithDefault False v values

eval' (Not x)   values = not (eval' x values)

eval' (And a b) values = eval' a values && eval' b values

eval' (Or  a b) values = eval' a values || eval' b values

eval' (Xor a b) values = eval' a values /= eval' b values
```

I was wondering if there was a way to pass the `values` table implicitly? Maybe with the help of Monads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, do not pass `values` at all:

```
eval' :: Expr -> M.Map Char Bool -> Bool
eval' e values = eval'' e

    where
    eval'' (Const c) = c
    eval'' (Var v) = M.findWithDefault False v values
    eval'' (Not x) = not (eval'' x)
    ...
```

Comment: Not only is this simpler, it's probably more efficient too. I believe it's called the static argument transformation.

Answer (score 13):

Monads would work, but in my opinion using `Applicative` is cleaner here:

```
eval' :: Expr -> M.Map Char Bool -> Bool
eval' (Const c) = pure c
eval' (Var v)   = M.findWithDefault False v
eval' (Not x)   = not <$> eval' x
eval' (And a b) = (&&) <$> eval' a <*> eval' b 
eval' (Or  a b) = (||) <$> eval' a <*> eval' b
eval' (Xor a b) = (/=) <$> eval' a <*> eval' b
```

This is using the `((->) r)` instance, like the `Reader` monad/applicative, but without the newtype wrapper.

Comment: I would have reached for the `Reader` monad, as acfoltzer did, but I like the clean look of this solution.

Comment: `Ambiguous occurrence 'Const': It could refer to either 'Main.Const' or 'Control.Applicative.Const'` Oh well, I wanted to rename my `Const` to `Val`, anyway :)

Comment: Or I could just `import Control.Applicative (pure, (<*>), (<$>))` :)

Comment: I usually think of the `((->) r)` instance as being a lightweight, inline version of `Reader` in code like this. If you get used to the style here, it can actually help clean up a lot of expressions where you take one argument and apply several things to it. e.g., compare `(&&) <$> (> 3) <*> (< 7)` to `\x -> x > 3 && x < 7`.

Answer (score 9):

This is exactly what the [Reader monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Reader.html) is for:

> The Reader monad (also called the Environment monad). Represents a
>   computation, which can read values from a shared environment, pass
>   values from function to function, and execute sub-computations in a
>   modified environment.

As Sjoerd notes, the monad gives more power here than you need, but you can still use the Reader monad for this problem without so much as typing `do`:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

import Control.Applicative ( (<$>), (<*>) )
import Control.Monad.Reader

data Expr = Const Bool
          | Var Char
          | Not Expr
          | And Expr Expr
          | Or Expr Expr
          | Xor Expr Expr
```

Just put your environment type as the first argument to the `Reader` type constructor, and your original result type as the second.

```
eval' :: Expr -> Reader (M.Map Char Bool) Bool
```

Instead of just `c` as the value of the `Const` case, use `return` to lift it into the monad:

```
eval' (Const c) = return c
```

When you need the environment for looking up the value of a variable, use `ask`. Using `do` notation, you can write the `Var` case like this:

```
eval' (Var v)   = do values <- ask
                     return (M.findWithDefault False v values)
```

I think it's nicer, though, to use `fmap` a.k.a. `<$>`:

```
eval' (Var v)   = M.findWithDefault False v <$> ask
```

Similarly, the unary `not` can be `fmap`ped over the result of the recursion:

```
eval' (Not x)   = not <$> eval' x
```

Finally, the [Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aApplicative) instance of Reader makes the binary cases pleasant:

```
eval' (And a b) = (&&) <$> eval' a <*> eval' b

eval' (Or  a b) = (||) <$> eval' a <*> eval' b

eval' (Xor a b) = (/=) <$> eval' a <*> eval' b
```

Then, to get it all started, here's a helper to create the initial environment and run the computation:

```
eval :: Expr -> [(Char,Bool)] -> Bool
eval exp env = runReader (eval' exp) (M.fromList env)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the extension [implicit parameters](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#implicit-parameters)? It could be quite helpful.

Comment: There was [a discussion on r/haskell about it recently](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/kbzjk/what_about_the_implicitparams_haskell_language/). The consensus appears to be that it's not that useful, mainly because they leak into type signatures, thus forcing you to either not use type signatures at all, or end up with  the same amount of boilerplate you were trying to get rid of.